# Find point maximising the distance from $x$ but still within a region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$ and the level set
$$
L = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f(x) = 0\}.
$$
Consider $\epsilon > 0$ fixed. Given a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I would like to find an expression for a point $y(x)$ such that:

- $y(x)$ is "along" the Jacobian:
  $$
  y(x) = x + J_f(x)^\top a \qquad a\in\mathbb{R}^m
  $$
- $y(x)$ satisfies $\|f(y(x))\| \leq \epsilon$
- $y(x)$ maximises the distance $\|y(x) - x\|$.

## Attempted Solution

I basically need to solve the following problem
$$
\max_{a\in\mathbb{R}^m} \|y(x) - x\|^2 \qquad \text{such that} \qquad \|f(y(x))\|\leq \epsilon 
$$
I tried constructing the Lagrangian
$$
\|y(x) - x\|^2 + \lambda(\epsilon^2 - \|f(y(x))\|^2)
$$

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical formula for the maximizer point for a general $f$?

Comment: @TonyMathew Yes. Either that or an approximation (e.g. using Taylor expansion)